# Active Record Rails Inheritance - Auto Type casting based on type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, multiple-inheritance

**My scenario**

---

-> User has many machines

-> Machines can have 5 types

-> each machine type has its own processing mechanism.

-> I want to use type column to see which class this row belongs to. (Rails inheritance approach) as explained in this link [Link](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/).

---

**My Question**

---

-> access a machine from database e.g machine = Machine.first

-> then call machine.process (this process method should be called based upon the  type of this machine). (I am expecting some type casting stuff here.)

**Note: Each machine type has its process implementation which is different from other and it implemented in its own class.**

I want to know best approach to implement this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement parent class `Machine` with common logic and children classes with personal logic.

```
rails g model machine type:string customer_id:integer
mkdir app/models/machines
touch app/models/machines/bmw.rb
touch app/models/machines/renault.rb
...
```

*app/models/machine.rb*

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  ...
  def country
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end
```

*app/models/machines/bmw.rb*

```
class Bmw < Machine
  ...
  def country
    :germany
  end
end
```

*app/models/machines/opel.rb*

```
class Renault < Machine
  ...
  def country
    :france
  end
end
```

For example:

- First bmw `Bmw.first`
- First any car `Machine.first`
- Get customer first Renault `Renault.first.customer`
- Country any car `Machine.all.sample.country`, this method will call from any the child class.

Comment: if we do like this where first row is of BMW class type.


Machine.first.country


which method will be called? Machine's or BMW's?

Comment: bmw.
If a children class is not of any method it call from the parent class.

Comment: my requirement was like this
u.machines.each do |m|
  #call child method here for its specific logic
  #for bmw its own method should be called etc. 
end

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't serve my requirement completely, although it was correct in its own context.

Answer (score 0):

After googling for some time I could figure out a gem that gave me exactly what I wanted.

[active_record-acts_as](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as) Gem.

Other links that I found useful were:

[Link1](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/)

[Link2](https://about.futurelearn.com/blog/refactoring-rails-sti/)

[Link3](http://hakunin.com/mti)